# Why isn't the menu1 function being invoked within the mehanika2 function in my code?

Tags: pygame

In my code, the menu1 function is launched first and I also have the mehanika function, it is needed to scan keystrokes (mehanika2 too), then when the button is pressed, the options function is launched and the mehanika2 function is already turned on in it, then when pressed, the startop loop should end and it ends and The menu1 function should still turn on, but it doesn’t turn on anymore, I sat for a couple of hours trying to figure it out, but it didn’t work, please help.

```
import pygame
import os


os.chdir("D:/Computer Science/denis")

bg_path = os.path.abspath("bg.jpg")

ball_path = os.path.abspath("ball.png")

nlo1_path = os.path.abspath("nlo1.png")
nlo2_path = os.path.abspath("nlo2.png")
button_path = os.path.abspath("knopa.png")
strelka_path = os.path.abspath("strelka.png")
font_path = os.path.abspath("GravitasOne-Regular.ttf")



bg = pygame.image.load(os.path.basename(bg_path))

ball = pygame.image.load(os.path.basename(ball_path))

nlo1 = pygame.image.load(os.path.basename(nlo1_path))
nlo2 = pygame.image.load(os.path.basename(nlo2_path))
button1 = pygame.image.load(os.path.basename(button_path))
button2 = pygame.image.load(os.path.basename(button_path))
button3 = pygame.image.load(os.path.basename(button_path))
strelka = pygame.image.load(os.path.basename(strelka_path))


pygame.init()

font = pygame.font.Font(font_path, 70)

party = 1.5

taburet = 0.8

divan = 1.0

help = False
nlo1_collided = False
nlo2_collided = False

x = True
y = True
y2 = True
y3 = True

startgame = True
startmenu = True
startop = True

window = pygame.display.set_mode((1920, 1080))
screen = pygame.Surface((1920, 1080))
pygame.display.set_caption("1,2,3,4,5,6")

ball_x = 922
ball_y = 502

nlo1_y = 405
nlo2_y = 405

button_width = 552
button_height = 143

strelka_width = 80
strelka_height = 60

strelka_x = 10
strelka_y = 10

exitbutton_x = 684
exitbutton_y = 705
exit_text = font.render("EXIT", True, (255, 255, 255)) 

playbutton_x = 684
playbutton_y = 305
play_text = font.render("PLAY", True, (255, 255, 255)) 

optionbutton_x = 684
optionbutton_y = 505
option_text = font.render("OPTIONS", True, (255, 255, 255)) 


def options():
    global menu1
    global startop
    while startop:

        mehanika2()
        pygame.display.update()

        for menu in pygame.event.get():
            if menu.type == pygame.QUIT:
                startop = False

        window.blit(screen, (0, 0))
        screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
        screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(strelka, (strelka_width, strelka_height)), (strelka_x, strelka_y))

def game():
    
    global startgame, x, y, y2, y3, taburet, divan, party, help, nlo1_collided, nlo2_collided, ball_x, ball_y, nlo1_y, nlo2_y

    while startgame:

        pygame.display.update()

        if y3:
            ball_y -= divan

        else:
            ball_y += divan

        if ball_y < 0:
            y3 = False

        if ball_y > 1005:
            y3 = True


        if x:
            ball_x += taburet
        
        else:
            ball_x -= taburet

        if ball_x > 1920 or ball_x < -75:
            startgame = False


        if y:
            nlo1_y -= party
            bogdan = True

        else:
            nlo1_y += party
            bogdan = False

        if nlo1_y < 0:
            y = False

        if nlo1_y > 810:
            y = True

        
        if y2:
            nlo2_y -= party
            bogdan2 = True

        else:
            nlo2_y += party
            bogdan2 = False

        if nlo2_y < 0:
            y2 = False

        if nlo2_y > 810:
            y2 = True

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                startgame = False
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN and bogdan:
                    y = False
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN and not bogdan:
                    y = True

                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and bogdan2:
                    y2 = False
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and not bogdan2:
                    y2 = True
        
        nlo1_rect = pygame.Rect(1550, nlo1_y, 25, 270)
        nlo2_rect = pygame.Rect(345, nlo2_y, 25, 270)
        ball_rect = pygame.Rect(ball_x, ball_y, 75, 75)

            
        if not ball_rect.colliderect(nlo1_rect) and not nlo1_collided:
            nlo1_collided = True
            help = False  
            nlo2_collided = False

        
        if not ball_rect.colliderect(nlo2_rect) and not nlo2_collided:
            nlo2_collided = True
            help = False 
            nlo1_collided = False 


        if ball_rect.colliderect(nlo1_rect) and not help:
            help = True
            x = False
            taburet = taburet + 0.1
            divan = divan + 0.1
            party = party + 0.05


        if ball_rect.colliderect(nlo2_rect) and not help:
            help = True
            x = True
            taburet = taburet + 0.1
            divan = divan + 0.1
            party = party + 0.05


        
        window.blit(screen, (0, 0))
        screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
        screen.blit(nlo1, (1550, nlo1_y))
        screen.blit(nlo2, (100, nlo2_y))
        screen.blit(ball, (ball_x, ball_y))



def menu1():
    
    global startmenu 
    global mouse_pos
    global menu1
    while startmenu:
    
        mehanika()
        pygame.display.update()
        
        for menu in pygame.event.get():
                if menu.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    startmenu = False


        window.blit(screen, (0, 0))
        screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))

        screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(button1, (button_width, button_height)), (exitbutton_x, exitbutton_y))
        screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(button2, (button_width, button_height)), (playbutton_x, playbutton_y))
        screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(button3, (button_width, button_height)), (optionbutton_x, optionbutton_y))

        screen.blit(option_text, (optionbutton_x + 60, optionbutton_y + 40))
        screen.blit(play_text, (playbutton_x + 150, playbutton_y + 40))
        screen.blit(exit_text, (exitbutton_x + 150, exitbutton_y + 40))

    
def mehanika():

    global startmenu 
    global mouse_pos
    global startop

    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if exitbutton_x < mouse_pos[0] < exitbutton_x + button_width and exitbutton_y < mouse_pos[1] < exitbutton_y + button_height:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                startmenu = False

    if playbutton_x < mouse_pos[0] < playbutton_x + button_width and playbutton_y < mouse_pos[1] < playbutton_y + button_height:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                startmenu = False
                game()

    if optionbutton_x < mouse_pos[0] < optionbutton_x + button_width and optionbutton_y < mouse_pos[1] < optionbutton_y + button_height:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                startmenu = False
                options()



def mehanika2():
    global startop
    mouse_pos2 = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if strelka_x < mouse_pos2[0] < strelka_x + strelka_width and strelka_y < mouse_pos2[1] < strelka_y + strelka_height:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                startop = False
                menu1()

menu1()
```